# Java [Android] - accessing instance variable of an object array in child class

Tags: java, android

I am quite a beginner and trying to access the instance variable of an object array in the child class but all I get is the initialized values instead of updated values. It is a little more complex but making it simple, the code can be put this way.

Seed.java

```
public class Seed {
    int weight = 0;
}
```

Apple.java

```
public class Apple {
    public Seed[] seed = new Seed[10];
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
Main Activity {

        public static Apple[] apple = new Apple[2];
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {         

               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
               apple[0] = new Apple();
               for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
               apple[0].seed[i] = new seed(); 
               assign();
             //and here new activity childActivity starts
        }

    public void assign() {
        for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
             apple[0].seed[i].weight = 10;
    } 
}
```

ChildActivity.java

```
ChildActivity extends mainActivity {

        //display a layout with a button   
        //upon button click 
        display();

     public void display() {
         //output to textview
         String.valueOf(apple[0].seed[0].weight);
}
```

gives me output of 0 instead of 10. I am not able to figure out whats wrong. I checked the values are being assigned properly in the mainActivity. I get no errors or crashes. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How and why are you assigning `10` to `apple[0].seed[i]`. Do you mean to do `apple[0].seed[i].weight = 10`?

Comment: These lines do not compile: "apple[0].seed[i] = new seed();" - "apple[0].seed[i] = 10;". The output of "String.valueOf(apple[0].seed[0]);" will not be "0", if the class Seed is like you told us. Could you please post correct and compilable code?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant apple[0].seed[i].weight = 10. Somehow missed it.

Comment: Okay, but what about "String.valueOf(apple[0].seed[0]);"? What do you think, this statement does? I am trying to tell you, that there is so much wrong code, that you should edit your post and correct everything. I think, you did not copy code snippets from your program, but simply wrote it manually here. And this does not equal to your program, I assume.

Comment: `String.valueOf(apple[0].seed[0]);` you won't get the string `0` from this. you get the object reference of your `seed[0]`

Comment: sorry, String.valueOf(apple[0].seed[0].weight) as well. which is going to the textview. This is just a sample code. The actual code is really long. But in short, this is where I am facing an issue.

Comment: Come on: What do you think the statement `String.valueOf(apple[0].seed[0].weight);` does? I tell you, it does nothing! No output, no assignment to a variable, nothing. As I told you, there are so many things wrong, because you simply wrote it manually and forgot several things, that it is difficult for us to help you. Why should we take effort to create an answer for you, if you do not take effort to write a good question with correct and compilable code?